# Last articles in front page

Tags: theming

I'm using Drupal 8 and I created a global layout with a custom theme I coded myself, and I added a custom content type for the home page. I have almost exactly what I want except for the following points.

1. I should have a block somewhere in the home page containing the last 3 articles posted on the website, and of course, a link to each of these articles. How am I supposed to do that? All answers I found were talking about Drupal 7.
2. I'm supposed to do the same as the last articles but for photos albums. I guess I have to use a module,  do I?

Comment: You tried using Views?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use thw Views module, which is a Drupal 8 core module.
   On admin/structure/views you can create a new view, even a block view. You can select which content type you want to display, the fields that should appear, and add all your limitations. After you save the view, on /admin/structure/block you can place the block on your preferred region.
2. If you have a content type for the photo albums, you can do exactly the same.